# why logback is running more efficiently than log4j from source code level, is it because of async appender?

Tags: performance, log4j, logback

Has anyone read through both logback and log4j source code, I read http://logback.qos.ch/reasonsToSwitch.html, it says "logback internals have been re-written to perform about ten times faster on certain critical execution paths. Not only are logback components faster, they have a smaller memory footprint as well."
Does anyone know how that happens from source code level?

Answer (score 0):

I would expect there to be many small improvements, not some magic new class.
They just started to measure performance and have unit tests for everything.

Logback sources are at https://github.com/qos-ch/logback

Log4j are at https://github.com/apache/log4j (not changed for 9 years, though http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4j/trunk/ shows a few commits for Log4j 2)